# Saving user password in yii2 fails

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-user

Am trying to update a users password but it fails to save it

This is the controller code:

```
public function actionChangepassword($id) {
    $model = new UserPass();
    $user = $this->findModel($id);

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        if ($model->validate()) {
            try {
                $user->setPassword($_POST['UserPass']['newpass']);

                if (!$user->save()) {
                    Yii::$app->getSession()->setFlash('success', 'Password changed to ');
                    return $this->redirect(['indexi/'.$user->password]);
                } else {
                    Yii::$app->getSession()->setFlash('error', 'Password not changed');
                    return $this->redirect(['index']);
                }
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                Yii::$app->getSession()->setFlash('error', "{$e->getMessage()}");
                return $this->render('changepassword', [
                    'model' => $model
                ]);
            }
        } else {
            return $this->render('changepassword', [
                'model' => $model
            ]);
        }
    } else {
        return $this->render('changepassword', [
            'model' => $model
        ]);
    }
}
```

When i check `var_dump($_POST['UserPass']['newpass'])` it has a value;

When i try changing the part `$user->setPassword($_POST['UserPass']['newpass']);`

```
$modeluser->password = $_POST['UserPass']['newpass'];
```

The password is saved but not hashed,

What could be wrong

This is the `setpassword` function

```
public function setPassword($password)
{
    $this->password = Yii::$app->security->generatePasswordHash($password);
}
```

Comment: Show full code of this action.

Comment: I have updated the question

Comment: I think you don't need to save password as password saved into `password_hash` field if you check original advanced templates login form. Also check how password reset action working in SiteController.php

Comment: Not to be annoying but your `if (!$user->save()) {` seems to have the resulting actions reversed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** Change

```
$user->setPassword($_POST['UserPass']['newpass']);
```

To

```
$user->newpass = $user->setPassword($_POST['UserPass']['newpass']);
```

**2)** Change

```
public function setPassword($password)
{
    $this->password = Yii::$app->security->generatePasswordHash($password);
}
```

To

```
public function setPassword($password)
{
    return Yii::$app->security->generatePasswordHash($password);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to look how it implemented in advanced template.